# Bitcoin transaction no confirmation unspent

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

https://blockchain.info/tx/9268c85e3f387e8ed98a1f1b8cd4aacececaeef9f1a0e029ca8ba12024668407?show_adv=true

This is the blockchain ID, not sure if its useful. Can someone please mine it if thats how it works

Answer (score 0):

Just give it time. Eventually miners will pick up the transaction and confirm it.

Just like it takes time for a payment to post to a debit card, so to does it take time for a payment to "post" on the network.

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided indicates a transaction fee of 105 satoshis per byte. You can view an estimated confirmation delay based on that fee amount here: https://bitcoinfees.21.co/

At the time I wrote this, it looks like up to a 4hr delay is expected. Though it might be somewhat longer than that, it seems likely that it will be a matter of hours rather than days.

Update, 7hrs later: The transaction has been confirmed.